# Usage of semi-colon

Tags: semicolons

Consider the following excerpt from a literature: "Getting quick access to a weapon's muzzle for inserting a bullet was easy; the gun was free to move backwards upto two meters."

The above sentence contains a semi-colon but a period would also have made sense. Is there any reason why the writer would.have gone for a semi-colon?

Comment: To connect the two thoughts more closely. A colon would have worked too.

Comment: As the sense conveyed is close, it should be OK with a semi-colon.